# Javascript Canvas - Organize square in a square

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, square

I have a set of square and I would like to organize them in a only square ( not a rectangle), which has the smallest size.

Here is an example, there are several possible solutions:

```
var square = [
{num : 1, height : "2cm", width : "2cm"},
{num : 2, height : "2cm", width : "2cm"},
{num : 3, height : "1cm", width : "1cm"},
{num : 4, height : "1cm", width : "1cm"}];
```

[image]

Is there an algorithm or a library in Javascript/jquery to realize this? I use Canvas.

Comment: Your looking for a rectangular bin packing algorithm. Here's a [script](https://github.com/jakesgordon/bin-packing) by Jake Gordon that does rectangle packing in javascript

Comment: Perfect, thank you !